# Why won't this navbar work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with my nav bar in internet explorer and I don't know how to solve it and have been trying to for hours. Below is the code that I think is the problem.

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--background);
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer [does not support CSS variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

You might be able to use [a polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables) to work around the limitation.