# document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--some-color', 'green') does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a custom css variable declared in a separate css file in a selector.

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: var(--altbg-color) !important;
}
```

This is not a root element. So not sure how css-vars-ponyfill will work in this case. I have tried that too but could not make it work. (I would be grateful if somebody can help me make it work.)

I am trying to set value to the variable through javascript (I am using AngularJS 1.3) using

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--some-color', 'green')
```

which works fine with Chrome & Firefox but not in  IE(11).

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 - does a polyfill / script exist for CSS variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [not supported in IE 11](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var).

You can only use CSS variables from IE edge 16 and above. However, it's partially supported in IE 15.

- In Edge 15, nested calculations with css variables are not computed and are ignored [see bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12143022/)
- In Edge 15 animations with css variables may cause the webpage to crash [see bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11676012/)
- In Edge 15 is not possible to use css variables in pseudo elements [see bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11495448/)

Though, there's a polyfill for this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill

This doesn't support IE edge 11. It starts supporting IE edge 12+. And without edge, it starts supporting from IE 9.

```
IE  Edge    Chrome  Firefox Safari
----------------------------------
9+  12+     19+     6+      6+
```

Comment: Any chance using css-vars-ponyfill? https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill

Comment: No. It does not. Updated my answer.

Comment: However, you may file a bug or issue in that polyfill and if the author thinks to provide the solution for IE edge 11, then you'll be lucky.

Comment: Here is a real polyfill that enables almost full support of CSS variables in IE11: https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties

Answer (score 0):

There is a polyfill, which enables almost complete support for CSS variables in IE11, including JS-integration:
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties
(i am the author)

The script makes use of the fact that IE has minimal custom properties support where properties can be defined and read out with the cascade in mind.
`.myEl {-ie-test:'aaa'} // only one dash allowed! "-"`
then read it in javascript:
`getComputedStyle( querySelector('.myEl') )['-ie-test']`

#### Demo:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties/ed6a269145661bfc6a43a5b69f06248fa760e766/demo.html