# Polyfill for css variables doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, polyfills

I am trying to set up polyfill for css color variables on Joomla website. I pick this solution from Aaron Barker:

https://codepen.io/aaronbarker/pen/MeaRmL

```
/*!
 * css-var-polyfill.js - v1.0.0
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Aaron Barker <http://aaronbarker.net>
 * Released under the MIT license
 *
 * Date: 2018-03-09
 */
let cssVarPoly = {
  init: function() {
    // first lets see if the browser supports CSS variables
    // No version of IE supports window.CSS.supports, so if that isn't supported in the first place we know CSS variables is not supported
    // Edge supports supports, so check for actual variable support
    if (window.CSS && window.CSS.supports && window.CSS.supports('(--foo: red)')) {
      // this browser does support variables, abort
      console.log('your browser supports CSS variables, aborting and letting the native support handle things.');
      return;
    } else {
      // edge barfs on console statements if the console is not open... lame!
      console.log('no support for you! polyfill all (some of) the things!!');
      document.querySelector('body').classList.add('cssvars-polyfilled');
    }

    cssVarPoly.ratifiedVars = {};
    cssVarPoly.varsByBlock = {};
    cssVarPoly.oldCSS = {};

    // start things off
    cssVarPoly.findCSS();
    cssVarPoly.updateCSS();
  },

  // find all the css blocks, save off the content, and look for variables
  findCSS: function() {
    let styleBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('style:not(.inserted),link[rel="stylesheet"]');

    // we need to track the order of the style/link elements when we save off the CSS, set a counter
    let counter = 1;

    // loop through all CSS blocks looking for CSS variables being set
    [].forEach.call(styleBlocks, function(block) {
      // console.log(block.nodeName);
      let theCSS;
      if (block.nodeName === 'STYLE') {
        // console.log("style");
        theCSS = block.innerHTML;
        cssVarPoly.findSetters(theCSS, counter);
      } else if (block.nodeName === 'LINK') {
        // console.log("link");
        cssVarPoly.getLink(block.getAttribute('href'), counter, function(counter, request) {
          cssVarPoly.findSetters(request.responseText, counter);
          cssVarPoly.oldCSS[counter] = request.responseText;
          cssVarPoly.updateCSS();
        });
        theCSS = '';
      }
      // save off the CSS to parse through again later. the value may be empty for links that are waiting for their ajax return, but this will maintain the order
      cssVarPoly.oldCSS[counter] = theCSS;
      counter++;
    });
  },

  // find all the "--variable: value" matches in a provided block of CSS and add them to the master list
  findSetters: function(theCSS, counter) {
    // console.log(theCSS);
    cssVarPoly.varsByBlock[counter] = theCSS.match(/(--.+:.+;)/g) || [];
  },

  // run through all the CSS blocks to update the variables and then inject on the page
  updateCSS: function() {
    // first lets loop through all the variables to make sure later vars trump earlier vars
    cssVarPoly.ratifySetters(cssVarPoly.varsByBlock);

    // loop through the css blocks (styles and links)
    for (let curCSSID in cssVarPoly.oldCSS) {
      // console.log("curCSS:",oldCSS[curCSSID]);
      let newCSS = cssVarPoly.replaceGetters(cssVarPoly.oldCSS[curCSSID], cssVarPoly.ratifiedVars);
      // put it back into the page
      // first check to see if this block exists already
      if (document.querySelector('#inserted' + curCSSID)) {
        // console.log("updating")
        document.querySelector('#inserted' + curCSSID).innerHTML = newCSS;
      } else {
        // console.log("adding");
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = newCSS;
        style.classList.add('inserted');
        style.id = 'inserted' + curCSSID;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
      }
    };
  },

  // parse a provided block of CSS looking for a provided list of variables and replace the --var-name with the correct value
  replaceGetters: function(curCSS, varList) {
    // console.log(varList);
    for (let theVar in varList) {
      // console.log(theVar);
      // match the variable with the actual variable name
      let getterRegex = new RegExp('var\\(\\s*' + theVar + '\\s*\\)', 'g');
      // console.log(getterRegex);
      // console.log(curCSS);
      curCSS = curCSS.replace(getterRegex, varList[theVar]);

      // now check for any getters that are left that have fallbacks
      let getterRegex2 = new RegExp('var\\(\\s*.+\\s*,\\s*(.+)\\)', 'g');
      // console.log(getterRegex);
      // console.log(curCSS);
      let matches = curCSS.match(getterRegex2);
      if (matches) {
        // console.log("matches",matches);
        matches.forEach(function(match) {
          // console.log(match.match(/var\(.+,\s*(.+)\)/))
          // find the fallback within the getter
          curCSS = curCSS.replace(match, match.match(/var\(.+,\s*(.+)\)/)[1]);
        });

      }

      // curCSS = curCSS.replace(getterRegex2,varList[theVar]);
    };
    // console.log(curCSS);
    return curCSS;
  },

  // determine the css variable name value pair and track the latest
  ratifySetters: function(varList) {
    // console.log("varList:",varList);
    // loop through each block in order, to maintain order specificity
    for (let curBlock in varList) {
      let curVars = varList[curBlock];
      // console.log("curVars:",curVars);
      // loop through each var in the block
      curVars.forEach(function(theVar) {
        // console.log(theVar);
        // split on the name value pair separator
        let matches = theVar.split(/:\s*/);
        // console.log(matches);
        // put it in an object based on the varName. Each time we do this it will override a previous use and so will always have the last set be the winner
        // 0 = the name, 1 = the value, strip off the ; if it is there
        cssVarPoly.ratifiedVars[matches[0]] = matches[1].replace(/;/, '');
      });
    };
    // console.log(ratifiedVars);
  },

  // get the CSS file (same domain for now)
  getLink: function(url, counter, success) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.overrideMimeType('text/css;');
    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        // console.log(request.responseText);
        if (typeof success === 'function') {
          success(counter, request);
        }
      } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
        console.warn('an error was returned from:', url);
      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      // There was a connection error of some sort
      console.warn('we could not get anything from:', url);
    };

    request.send();
  }
};

cssVarPoly.init();
```

On my website, I am loading dozen of css files so I tried to put whole JS code from CodePen to the start of my HEAD section, also I tried put in on the bottom of HTML file -> no result.

Please, am I missing something?

Comment: If the polyfill is working correctly in Codepen try to run it onLoad after style sheets have been loaded. I'm not sure if styles work then same as scripts (stops execution of next script so you can put the code at the end), maybe you need onload event.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for tip. I tried it but without result. Any ideas? Or how can I debug it? Thank you!

Comment: Check this [IE11 - does a polyfill / script exist for CSS variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203834/387194) Maybe this one will be working. Maybe you didn't found it because it's called ponyfill.

Comment: Thank you so much for advise! I finally managed it to work thanks to good docs for Ponyfill!