# CSS variables not working with IE11. Any poly fill should be added?

Tags: angular, theming, css-variables

We are trying to provide an option to user to change theme of our application (using theme module) which is developing with Angular. For this we are checking CSS variables which can have variable value from theme file.

When we tested with small POC, all latest browsers supporting CSS variables but not with IE11 or older IE versions. I read some articles saying it will not work with older browsers. And also went through [IE11 - does a polyfill / script exist for CSS variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables), but could not understand how to implement with angular application. Can anyone help me with sample code with Angular and support in IE browsers too?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can use postcss as well in the bundling process to fix it. It will allow you to use more new features for css and can become a SASS/SCSS similar tool. https://time2hack.com/2018/03/postcss-css-preprocessor-in-javascript/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IE11 - does a polyfill / script exist for CSS variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables)