# Theme switcher in MEAN stack application

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, theming

In my application,

I have implemented theming using an *angular material theme* 
but it is **so heavy** for my project...

> that's why I don't want to depend on it.

After that I have implemented using the CSS Variables it is working fine

but it doesn't have full support you can check it over [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=CSS%20Variables).

**QUESTION:** *anyone can suggest another way?*

Comment: Do you want to support all legacy browser ? Because now a days, all modern frameworks moving ahead to drop support for legacy browser.

Comment: @GRD I wish I could drop them but I need all browser's support.

Comment: Then you need to add polyfil of css variable which adds  support for legacy browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables