# Set property value of class A to value of class B

Tags: css

Is it possible in CSS to set the value of one property of a class as the same property value of another class ?

e.g.:

```
.classA{
color: blue;
}
.classB{
color:[likeClassA];
}
```

Comment: Use [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

Comment: Note, what you're referring to are CSS "properties" and not "attributes".

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible but you could do this as an alternative

`.classA ,.class B{
    color:blue;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS (i.e. not a precompiled solution) you can use CSS custom properties:

```css
:root {
   --mycolor: blue;
}

.classA {
   color: var(--mycolor);
}

.classB {
   color: var(--mycolor);
}
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

---

Please note that `var()` is not supported in IE11 or below. There are some solutions though including polyfills: [CSS custom properties polyfill for ie11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429913/css-custom-properties-polyfill-for-ie11)

Comment: Terrible support in IE

Comment: I am aware. But there are ways around it. The real solution is to use SASS here, but I am trying to provide a native answer.

Comment: Found it interesting that the YouTube css is riddled with var stuff :-)